# Initialize an object based on any sub-class of an abstract base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I've got a templated abstract base class A and a number of classes that inherit from it:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
virtual void do_something() override {...}
};

template <typename T>
class C : public A<T> {
virtual void do_something() override {...}
}; 

template <typename T>
class D : public A<T> {
virtual void do_something() override {...}
};
```

Now I want to define a class that manages an **array** of any one of these objects. So for example:

```
auto cm = Multi<double, 3>(c); // Holds an array of 3 C<double>
auto bm = Multi<long, 5>(b); // Holds an array of 5 B<long>
```

What is the correct way to *define* this class so that it can be *initialized* with the type of object it is holding (`B`,`C`,`D`, etc.), ideally without creating named objects that don't get used?

I know I can use pointers to the base class `A` to make the array class generic, but I can't figure out how to get the class to initialize effectively.

I would be ok using templating on the `Multi` class to have it templated to a specific type (`B`,`C`, or `D`), but I haven't found a way of restricting the template to accept only subclasses of `A`.

**Edit:**

Here's what I want for the multi. Essentially I want to be able to call `Multi.do_something()` and have it call that method for each object in its array. The example also shows the methods that haven't worked for me.

```
template <typename T, int N>
class Multi {
public:
  Multi(A<T> obj){  // Doesn't work because you can't create an instance of A
    for (auto obj : _objs){
        obj = std::make_unique<obj>();
    }
  }

  Multi(A<T> *obj) { // Could work, but doesn't work for anonymous objects because they're r-values
     ...
  }
  
  void do_something(){
     for (auto obj : _objs){
        obj->do_something();
     }
  }
private:
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<A<T>>, N> _objs;
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to have an array that can hold `A<int>` and `A<double>` at the same time?

Comment: Before you do anything else, add a `virtual ~A() {}` to `A`.

Comment: please show what you tried.

Comment: it is unclear what you want or what issue you encountered. If you want an array of `C`s thats just `std::array<C,42>`, same for array of `B`s: `std::array<B,42>`

Comment: You probably want to use something like `std::array<std::variant<B, C, D>, 10>`.

Comment: do you perhaps want some `Multi` (ie not a `CMulti` and not a `BMulti`) that can be initialized either with a couple of `C`s, eg `auto cm = Multi(c1,c2,c3);` to get a `Multi` with an array of `C`s or with a couple of `B`s, eg `auto bm = Multi(b1,b2,b3);` to get a `Multi` with an array of `B`s?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai - yes, more or less! But ideally I'd like to be able to say `auto cm = Multi<3>(c);` and get a `Multi` with an array of 3 `C`s.

Comment: then your text is a little misleading. You say you want "`BMulti` which holds a `std::array` of `B`s" and you want "`CMulti`, which holds a `std::array` of `C`s", but If i understand correctly you want one `Multi`

Comment: `// Doesn't work because you can't create an instance of A` why is the template argument of `Multi` not just `A` or `B` or `C` ? Ie it contains a `std::array<T, N> _objs;` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I would be fine to do that, but then you could also instantiate it with values of `T` that don't inherit from `A`. If I could restrict the values of the template parameter to `A` and classes that inherit from it, that would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using a `std::variant` approach, and your `Multi` approach with `std::unique_ptr`.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

using std::array;
using std::cout;
using std::make_unique;
using std::size_t;
using std::string;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::variant;
using std::visit;

using unit = std::monostate;

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// Explicit deduction guide needed for C++17, not needed as of C++20.
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

template <typename T>
struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default;
    A() = default;
    A(A const&) = default;
    auto operator=(A const&) -> A& = default;
    virtual void some_function() = 0;
    virtual auto clone() const -> unique_ptr<A> = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
    void some_function() override {
        cout << "B some_function\n";
    }
    virtual auto clone() const -> unique_ptr<A<T>> override {
        return make_unique<B>(*this);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct C : A<T> {
    void some_function() override {
        cout << "C some_function\n";
    }
    virtual auto clone() const -> unique_ptr<A<T>> override {
        return make_unique<C>(*this);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct D : A<T> {
    void some_function() override {
        cout << "D some_function\n";
    }
    virtual auto clone() const -> unique_ptr<A<T>> override {
        return make_unique<D>(*this);
    }
};

template <typename T, int N>
class Multi {
public:
    Multi(A<T> const& obj){  // Doesn't work because you can't create an instance of A
        for (auto& ptr : _objs){
            ptr = obj.clone();
        }
    }

    void do_something() {
        for (auto& ptr : _objs){
            ptr->some_function();
        }
    }

    void set(size_t i, A<T> const& obj) {
        _objs[i] = obj.clone();
    }

private:
    array<unique_ptr<A<T>>, N> _objs;
};

int main() {
    using BB = B<int>;
    using CC = C<double>;
    using DD = D<string>;
    using var_t = variant<unit, BB, CC, DD>;
    array<var_t, 10> a;
    a[0] = BB();
    a[3] = CC();
    a[8] = DD();

    size_t i{};
    for (auto&& x : a) {
        cout << "a[" << i++ << "]: ";

        visit(overloaded{
            [](unit) { cout << "{}\n"; },
            [](auto& aa) { aa.some_function(); },
        }, x);
    }

    cout << "-------------------\n";

    Multi<int, 9> multi(B<int>{});
    multi.set(5, C<int>{});
    multi.set(6, D<int>{});
    multi.do_something();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the trick is that C++ allows you to cast a `B`/`C`/`D` object to an `A const&`?

Comment: There's a lot here I don't actually need. Just the `A const&` and the `clone` function does it.

Comment: @GedaliahKnizhnik • You're welcome!  I wasn't sure what your real code was trying to do.  So I figured to pitch a few suggestions to you.  The `A const&` is because dynamic dispatch *requires* using pointers or references; pass-by-value would slice.